# Calculate percentage of a user defined number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Sk8erPeter/kxrTS/) snippet to calculate how many check boxes a user clicks on, I then have a submit button underneath where I'm trying to get it to display the percent. For example, if they clicked on 8 checkboxed out of 10, then it should display 80% underneath.

I tried the following bit of PHP code

```
$x = "<?php if(isset($_POST['count-checked-checkboxes']))?>";;
$total = 500;
$percentage = ($x*100)/$total;
```

where x would be the number of checkboxes checked but when I tried to echo $percentage I got an underfined variable error: Notice: Undefined variable: percentage"

Is there was I can do this using Javascript or Jquery perhaps?

Comment: What's going on here? `$x = "<?php if(isset($_POST['count-checked-checkboxes']))?>";;` That doesn't look right. Which variable does it say is undefined?

Comment: 100 multiplied by a string, looks a logic error to me ..?

Comment: It says $percentage is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with Javascript:

```
$checkboxes.change(function(){
    var countCheckboxes = $checkboxes.length;
    var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    var percentage = Math.round(100 * countCheckedCheckboxes / countCheckboxes);
    $('#percentage-checked-checkboxes').text(percentage);
});
```

See: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KIKO_Software/v4fhyz19/4/)

However, the percentage won't be known on the server now.

Comment: I wanted it display both how many are checked and the percentage underneath, but that was simple to modify. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't know how many checkboxes there are. You can do this in jQuery instead, and if you need it in PHP, set a hidden element that sends the total number of checkboxes.

```html
<div class="count-checkboxes-wrapper">
    <span id="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span> of
    <span id="count-total-checkboxes">0</span> 
    (<span id="percentage-checked-checkboxes">0</span> %) checked
</div>
```

If you need to send the total number of checkboxes to PHP, you can add a hidden input element within your form

```html
<input type="hidden" id="checkedCheckboxesPercentageInput" name="checkedCheckboxesPercentage" value="0" />
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $checkboxes = $('#devel-generate-content-form td input[type="checkbox"]')

    $("#count-total-checkboxes").text($checkboxes.length);

    $checkboxes.change(function(){
        var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length,
            percentageCheckedCheckboxes = countCheckedCheckboxes / $checkboxes.length * 100;

        $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);
        $("#percentage-checked-checkboxes").text(percentageCheckedCheckboxes);

        // If you're sending it to PHP, add the hidden input and uncomment below
        // $("#checkedCheckboxesPercentageInput").val($checkboxes.length);
    });
});
```

If you add the hidden element, you can then get the value in PHP through `$_POST['checkedCheckboxesPercentage'];`.

See your revised fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4mrjyxod/